# Need help figuring out a segmentation fault in ARM

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, machine-code

so I recently received a project for a 2nd year computer science module, where we did computer architecture. We were instructed to write ARM Assembly code to output the fibonacci sequence for n=15 as well as n=30.

I have tried checking out multiple resources online, but ARM is not as widely used, nor supported in 2020 anymore. I have been able to compile and run my code, however it tells me "segmentation fault" and outputs the wrong number (139).

I have been stuck for the past weekend, attempting multiple fixes, with no luck. If anyone could just guide me in the right direction, or help me identify my logical or syntax error, it would be great. I will post the code below, and thank you so much in advance!!!

```
.global  main
.func main
main:
        LDR R5,=0x50000000    ; load mem address
        MOV R1,#5             ; number comparisons

.loop:
        LDR R2,[R5]         ; load 1st number
        ADD R6, R5,#04      ; increment address to next number
        LDR R3, [R6]        ; load 2nd number
        ADD R4, R2, R3

        STR R4, [R6,#4]     ;store in next mem location
        MOV R5, R6

        SUBS R1, #01        ; decrement counter
        BNE .loop           ; loop mechanism
        NOP
.endfunc
BX LR
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to find where the segementation fault occurs?  If yes, where?

Comment: How do you know the number is found at address `0x50000000`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I used a YouTube video as guidelines, and they used that indexing, but I think it might be dependent on the emulator being used. We are urged to use putty, a linux based emulator. I have been using emu8086 and that. A bit clueless when it comes to this, because we only got a 40 page pdf on the matter.

Comment: EMU8086 is for 8086 only.  It won't run ARM programs. PuTTY is not an emulator. 
 It's a program to establish terminal connections to other systems, it won't run any ARM programs for you.  What exactly do you run this program on?  How do you assemble and link it?  I need to know all of this so I can understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. With the whole pandemic, the university was forced to close their doors. So we are using a vpn to connect to the university's network, then using putty and a special generated IP to connect to the few rasberry pi's that are set up in the university's computer labs. Then we have been using putty commands, like as -o etc, gcc -o etc, ./name echo ; $? In order to compile, run etc. Hope this helps clarify the given situation, thanks again for the help and effort!

Comment: Ah, I see.  In this case, The address `0x50000000` is incorrect.  How are the numbers given to your program?

Comment: Oh okay, don't really know how to respond to this, just passed normal numbers/integers by using a # before the number, so don't otherwise know how to obtain the physical address in memory, or how to pass them as parameters, if that makes sense

Comment: What I mean is that your program somehow needs to know that `n=15`.  How do you specify the value of `n`? Do you mean this line:  `MOV R1,#5`?  And how do you allocate space for the intermediate results?  The program you posted doesn't seem to do anything like that.  It just uses a random address which leads to the crash you observe.  I'm almost ready to post an answer; just need your response to these points.

Comment: okay, the `MOV R1,#5` line is just the line where I keep the N value essentially, which is why I decrement (SUBS) it in the loop. I just used 5 as a test case, but I understand what you mean by saying it is returning a random address, because at first I thought the 139 might be hexadecimal, so I converted, but it did not return the correct fibonacci value. Hope this is helpful, you have been very much so far, and I genuinely appreciate it!

Comment: I will attach the link to the video I used, but I am starting to understand a bit better now. I understand that each pc/rasberry pi/emulator has different addressing, so I would have to cater for that and make sure I use the correct address/indexing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v9IP_OklSk&pbjreload=101&ab_channel=NHCELabExperimentVideos

Comment: That video is so bad... please don't try to follow random Youtube videos like that.  It'll just confuse you.  Anyway, I'm writing an answer now.

Comment: haha yeah I know, but sadly ARM is not big anymore, so there were about 3/5 videos to chose from, and that was one of only 2 English ones XD thank you man, really really appreciate it, my lecturer hasn't been helpful, and it is daunting to figure out a language you have not ever used, nor will ever use, seeing as we focus on java and C mostly

Comment: I see.  Also, please make sure not to submit this as homework for your course.  Copying a program from a video is academic dishonesty.

Comment: No I won't, always try to learn from an example, and apply it in my own way, because otherwise there was no point in doing the exercise. Want to just understand the basics, in order to be able to do all the other practical's/algorithms required of us. Thanks again

Comment: *but ARM is not as widely used, nor supported in 2020 anymore* - You have it backwards: ARM seems to be taking over the world, including Apple's upcoming desktops / laptops.  (Although that will be 64-bit ARM, aka AArch64.) You don't need a zillion good or bad tutorials like you'd find for x86, you just need a few good ones.  The vendor docs are not quite as easy to get for ARM as for x86, but there is lots of good ARM info out there. e.g. http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/barrel-shifter.html and other parts of that site are great.  Maybe less youtube videos, but so what?

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the link, will definitely check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code crashes because you try to read/write a random address.  This crash is translated by your shell into exit status 139 according to the formula 128 + signal number (`SIGSEGV` is signal 11).

You should generally not simply pick some random address and store your data there.  This almost always crashes and if it does not, it's still likely that the memory at that address is used by something else in your program.

To fix this issue, you should allocate some memory explicitly and use the address of that memory region.  The easiest way to do so is to use *static memory allocation* and place the data you need in the `.data` section:

```
        .section .data    ; enter .data section
data:   .int 0            ; first number
        .int 1            ; second number
```

Here, `data` is a *symbol.*  You can give it whatever name you want, but its name must be unique in the source file.  You can then load the address of `data` in your program instead of hard-coding `0x50000000`:

```
        ldr r5, =data     ; load the address of data
```

Note that if you want to place code in the file after defining your variables, you need to switch back to the `.text` section.  Code (i.e. *program text*) always goes into the `.text` section.

```
        .section .text    ; switch back to the .text section
```

At the beginning of the file, the current section is implicitly the `.text` section, but it's generally a good idea to always switch sections explicitly before emitting any sort of code or data.

It is also possible to place *uninitialised data* in the `.bss` section.  This is especially useful if you want to allocate an array of data and don't want to type out that many `.int` directives.

```
        .section .bss     ; enter .bss section
data:   .space 8          ; reserve 8 bytes of memory
```

Contrary to the `.data` section, it is not possibly to specify initial values for memory in the `.bss` section.  The initial value will always be a series of zeroes.

Comment: thank you so much for the input! But is the rest of my logic and syntaxing correct? I will hop onto my editor and try applying these tips, and most likely get back to you if I am still struggling, or mark this as answered if I succeed. Thanks again, hope you enjoy the rest of your day.

Comment: @KryptonZA  Read the code to understand what it does.  It looks like it's trying to produce an array of Fibonacci numbers in memory.  It doesn't seem to return anything.  I recommend you to try and come up with some logic on your own to solve this exercise instead of copying code you don't understand.  Sketch the logic in pseudo code first and then translate each bit into instructions.  Try to use registers, not memory as variables if possible.

Comment: Okay, but like I said all I have is a 40 page pdf that just covers basic operations, so I am still trying to figure out how I can output the content of a register in order to be able to evaluate the correctness of the algorithm. This was just the final exercise of a 2 week block of the module in which we got nothing but the pdf. So did not pour hours into this like with java, especially seeing it was just 2 weeks, and never being used again. Would I not be able to only work with registers, instead of using memory? or would that complicate it too much?

Comment: @KryptonZA I see.  You should be able to solve this exercise just fine using just registers.  To return a value to the operating system as an exit status, place it in `r0` right before your `main` function returns.  You can also print numbers by invoking the `printf` function from the libc.

Comment: okay awesome, thanks for the tip.  but if I will only be using registers, because we are only expected to return the values, nothing fancy, how will that differ to what I am currently doing. Because till my understanding, I only use memory in the `LDR R5,=0x50000000` and `ADD R6, R5,#04` and `STR R4, [R6,#4]` lines. how would I approach this workaround using only registers to store and decrement values

Comment: @KryptonZA You also access memory in the other `LDR` instructions.  Think of what variables you need and put each variable into a different register.  Sketch the algorithm out in pseudo code and translate each step into assembly.  The code you provided does something slightly different (namely, it produces a table of Fibonacci numbers).  A solution to your homework is quite a bit simpler.

Comment: Ok ill try, need to submit this by tomorrow, and don't really have much time to do this seeing as I have other modules and assignments, for which I will actually have to be able to do the stuff, not just submit it like this one and never do anything related again, so was hoping someone on here would be able to post sample code for me to analyze and alter to be relevant to my scenario, but I understand that that would be asking too much. Anyway, thanks for all the tips, but I physically don't have time to go study a language I won't ever use again after Tuesday